# php multiple classes and methods with same name

Tags: php, class, methods, naming

If I call "myClass::getItems()" from the "workingCLass" which getId method will be called? The one that echos "hello" or "bye"? Thank you.

```
class myClass extends otherClass {
   function getId(){
      echo "hello";
   }
}


class otherClass{
   function getItems(){
      $this->getId();
   }
   function getId(){
      echo "bye";
   }
}


class workingClass extends myClass {
   function __construct(){
      $this->getItems();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one with `"hello"`, because you explicitly specified which one to call.

The problem, though, is that it's not static and you call it in a static context.

EDIT: With `$this`, it will not call anything, because there's no `getItems()` in the `workingClass`. If `workingClass` extended the `otherClass` it would do the `"bye"` thingie.

Comment: Your right, it should say $this->getItems(). If I did not have the "getId" method in "myClass", would it echo "bye"?

Answer (score 2):

This will result in fatal error, since you are calling  this method statically (`::`) and inside this method you are using `$this` special variable, that refers to `workingClass`(object from which it was called) and `workingClass` has no `getId` method.

OK, now after fixing the example I can say that it will output 'hello', because when calling method from the object (`$this->`) PHP will always run one defined in latest child class.

Comment: Yea your right, I messed up in my example, I am looking at someone code and did not want to copy paste a ton of stuff.

Comment: it will still be fatal error... If `workingClass` will extend `myClass` then it will work and will call `getId()` from `myClass` (hello).

Comment: @milan - now this example make sense, I've updated my answer with some explanation.

Comment: "PHP will always run one defined in latest child class", that is what I did not know. Thanks.